# Syntax of importing multiple classes from a module

Tags: python

I'm reading some code which contains the following import statement:

```
from threading import local as thread_local, Event, Thread
```

At first this syntax puzzled me, but I think it is equivalent to:

```
from threading import local as thread_local
from threading import Event
from threading import Thread
```

Can anyone confirm whether this is the case?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise how could you define more than one alias in an import? `from threading import local as t_local, Event as Harambe, Thread as Banana`.

Comment: Yes, I'm positive! I think whole Python community will be positive as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check this on the official documentation. Here's the [documentation for the `import` syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import):

> ```
> import_stmt     ::=  "import" module ["as" name] ( "," module ["as" name] )*
>                      | "from" relative_module "import" identifier ["as" name]
>                      ( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
>                      | "from" relative_module "import" "(" identifier ["as" name]
>                      ( "," identifier ["as" name] )* [","] ")"
>                      | "from" module "import" "*"
> module          ::=  (identifier ".")* identifier
> relative_module ::=  "."* module | "."+
> name            ::=  identifier
> ```

Note how you always have the `import module ["as" name]` and `identifier ["as" name]`, including in the list definition:

```
( "," identifier ["as" name] )*
```

This means a comma `,` followed by an identifier, optionally assigned with `as` to a name and the `)*` means "this group can be repeated zero or more times, which includes the example you provided.

This is also explained on the same page a bit later on:

> The `from` form uses a slightly more complex process:
>
> 1. find the module specified in the `from` clause, loading and initializing it if necessary;
> 2. for each of the identifiers specified in the import clauses:
>
>    1. check if the imported module has an attribute by that name
>    2. if not, attempt to import a submodule with that name and then check the imported module again for that attribute
>    3. if the attribute is not found, `ImportError` is raised.
>    4. otherwise, **a reference to that value is stored in the local namespace, using the name in the `as` clause if it is present, otherwise
>         using the attribute name**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

Check out all the ways that one can import a module in python:
https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement

Answer (score 0):

Yes the two syntaxes are equivalent and also equivalent with:

```py
from threading import (
   local as thread_local, 
   Event, 
   Thread
)
```

Answer based on the title:

> Syntax of importing multiple classes from a module

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
  QWidget, 
  QLCDNumber,
  QSlider,
  QVBoxLayout, 
  QApplication)
```