# Import a list of classes from a module

Tags: python, class, import

Looking to import a list of classes and then use them later in the script. Therefore, the `from x import *` logic does not work. Here is a more specific layout of what I am looking to do.

```
class_list = [x, y, z, zz, zzz]
from my_module import class_list
```

and then later on in the code still be able to call `x.random_attribute`. Not sure if this is possible!

To clarify I am trying to avoid the following:

```
from my_module import x, y, z, zz, zzz
```

as I have about 50 class objects I am importing and more will be added over time. Would love to have the list as a separate object.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850390/syntax-of-importing-multiple-classes-from-a-module

Comment: If you are in control of `my_module`, you can add the classes to `my_module.__all__`; then `from my_module import *` will import just your desired classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class_list = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'zz', 'zzz']
for c in class_list:
    exec('from my_module import ' + c)
```

Comment: Beware of insecurities that you run into due to usage of eval. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings#:~:text=eval()%20will%20allow%20malicious,hard%20to%20do%20this%20properly.